# Why searching for the middle item in an array of 100 is faster than in an array of 10 items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I made some tests to check this but is quite not expected: http://jsperf.com/value-in-array-or-object

You can run those tests too..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not faster. It appeared faster in your tests because you were assigning rather than comparing in the tests for 50 and 100 items:

```
if(a100[x] = 'item50'){
    break;
}
```

The test with 10 items was correct:

```
if(a10[x] === 'item5'){
    break;
}
```

See [updated test cases here](http://jsperf.com/value-in-array-or-object/2).

Comment: oh!! shame on me! then I have a question about why objects with 50 items is faster than one with only 10. (in google chrome, because in safari is exacly the same)